# How to define $x^n$ where $x=\pm 1$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$?

Tags: function-construction, variable-definitions

I do not know how I can define $x^{n}$ in Mathematica, where $x=\pm 1$ and $n=1,2,3,\ldots$.

For even values of $n$ we simply have that $x^{n}=1$. While for odd values of $n$ we have that $x^{n}=x$. That is, $${x^n} = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
1&,&{{\rm{if }}\;n\;{\rm{ is\; even}}}\\
x&,&{{\rm{if }}\;n\;{\rm{ is\; odd}}}
\end{array}} \right.$$

Thank you, Jack

Comment: `Piecewise[]`, `OddQ[]`, and `EvenQ[]` should prove useful.

Comment: Thanks. I did try that but I don't know what to write (or how to write $x^{n}$) on the left hand side.

Comment: Does it really have to be a superscript (which is used for exponentation by default)? You can do something like `xn[x : (-1 | 1), n_Integer?Positive] := Piecewise[(* stuff *)]`…

Comment: Thanks. I will try that and let you know.

Comment: If you really mean that x=+/-1 then why not `(-1)^n`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Boole`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole.html) like this:

```
xn[n_Integer?Positive] := x^Boole[OddQ[n]]
```

Comment: Iverson saves the day once more. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[f]
f[n_ /; EvenQ[n] && n > 0, x_] := 1
f[n_ /; OddQ[n] && n > 0, x_] := x
```